# MongoDB query for deep embedded data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a collection of documents structured like

```
{
    "group": "GroupA",
    "people": {
        "Joe": [
            {
                "type": "home",
                "address": "123 Fake St"
            },
            {
                "type": "work",
                "address": "345 Work Pl"
            }
        ],
        "Mary": [
            {
                "type": "home",
                "address": "1 Main St"
            },
            {
                "type": "work",
                "address": "345 Work Pl"
            }
        ],
        "Bob": [
            {
                "type": "home",
                "address": "1 Main St"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I query for a group that has a person who has an address of, say "345 Work Pl". I was trying to use $elemMatch but that seems to onl query into the first level which isn't even a list. I want the whole document where there's at least one match.

Comment: Is changing your structure an option ? If yes, you should change to `"people": [{name: "Joe", address:[{..}, {..}]}, {name:"Bob" ...}]`. If no and on version 3.6 you can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation to search for addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can move to this structure would be better and easier for you to make more queries

Here is the idea

```
// group collection
[
  {
    id: '1'
    name: 'groupA'
  }
]

// people collection
[
  {
    id: 1
    name: 'Joe', 
    type: 'home',
    address: '123 Fake St',
    group: 1
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mary',
    address: '1 Main St'
    group: 1
  }
]
```

In this kind of structure you can retrieve the data you want by doing this:

```
db.people.find({ address: '345 Work Pl' })
```

as you can see is much easier.

---

Now if you need to show the name of the group each time you can store it inside each person.

Comment: That would be nice, but I am only consuming the data. I can't affect its format.